# Error converting SOAP-XML response to JSON

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to convert a WS SOAP-XML response to JSON format, but I got the following error:

```
error: ballerina.lang.errors:Error, message: failed to get xml payload: failed to parse xml: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
```

I think it is because the response starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap....">
```

Is there a way to remove the first line? Then I could use XmlToJSON.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the same issue as in https://github.com/ballerinalang/ballerina/issues/3601

Currently, there's no way to remove the first line without converting to XML. But I assume that's where you get that error.

However, above XML declaration line (`<?xml version="1.0"...>`) is added only if the payload has been built prior to getting it as XML. Is there any place in your code, where the response is converted to string (eg: via `req.getStringPayload()` method), before getting the payload as XML? One workaround is to eliminate that, or get the payload as XML as the first thing.

This issue will be fixed in the upcoming release though.